# Variable variables for data retrieval?

Tags: php, mysql

Firstly, been an avid reader of stackoverflow since I started dabbling with php about a year ago.  Can normally find answers to most questions, but am struggling with this one.

I have read a lot of posts that STRONGLY discourage the use of variable variables in php, to the point where it seems the general consensus is avoid them like the plague.  Whereas I understand certain scenarios may open security holes, I need to understand what (if any) implications there are for using them in the following MySQL data retrieval context.

Among other things, my web app deals with processing a number of different client questionnaires with a high number of questions.  Example snippets of database structure and a questionnaire class is given below to illustrate my question (with all irrelevant code removed for clarity).  All MySQL fields and class properties have the same naming convention.

My code works like a charm, but I need somebody to tell my why I shouldn't be using it!

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE `history` (
  `historyID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `clientID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `q1` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `q2` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `q3` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `q4` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,

  //..all the way to..

  `q90` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`historyID`),
  KEY `clientID` (`clientID`),
  CONSTRAINT `childdevq_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`clientID`) REFERENCES `client` (`clientID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=134 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

php Class:

```
class history {

    private $db; // MySQL db object

    public $historyID;
    public $created;
    public $clientID;
    public $q1;
    public $q2;
    public $q3;
    public $q4;

    //..all the way to..

    public $q90;

    public function __construct($db){
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    private function populateFields($row){
        foreach ($row as $field=>$value){
            $this->{$field} = htmlspecialchars($value);
        }
    }

    public function getHistory($historyID){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM history WHERE historyID = {$historyID};";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows){
            $row = $result->fetch_array();
            $this->populateFields($row);
            return 'success';
        } else {
            return 'no results';
        }
    }
}
```

The alternative would be:

```
    private function populateFields($row){
        $this->historyID = htmlspecialchars($row['historyID']);
        $this->clientID = htmlspecialchars($row['clientID']);
        $this->q1 = htmlspecialchars($row['q1']);
        $this->q2 = htmlspecialchars($row['q2']);
        $this->q3 = htmlspecialchars($row['q3']);
        $this->q4 = htmlspecialchars($row['q4']);

        //..all the way to..

        $this->q90 = htmlspecialchars($row['q90']);
    }
```

...which seems like a lot of unnecessary code.  Am I just being plain lazy?

Anyway, I don't pretend to be anything other than a complete amateur, so please rip me to shreds nicely! :-)

Comment: Do you really need 90 attribute in your class ? can't you have an attribute `$q` which is an array of 90 elements ? you could so make index in the construct method (with a loop), and then populate with `$this->q[$i] = htmlspecialchars($row['q'.$i]);`, with $i the keys of your $q attribute in a foreach... The main problem with your actual code is that there is no clue about what attributes will be filled, we have to know the database scheme to check it all... if you fill an array in the construct, it would be cristal clear...

Comment: Just as a sugestion you could make $q an array and populate it using the numbers (I think). so `$q[1]`, `$q[4]`. When you foreach through the array you can see what the index id is I think (need to try this out)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in my comment (and @Random's) why not store you q's as an array, here is a bit of sample code I knocked up to give you an idea

```
private function populateFields($row)
{
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        if(substr($key, 0, 1) === 'q')
            $index = substr($key, 1);
            $this->q[$index] = htmlspecialchars($value);
        } else {
            $this->$key = htmlspecialchars($value);
        }
    }
}

// Later when you want to see what is in q
foreach ($this->q as $index => $value) {
    // your q number
    echo $index;
}
```

As a side note if you designed the DB to be like this then a better approach would be a table that holds the questions against a questionnaire with a join. If you didn't design the table, find who did and shoot them ;)

Comment: be careful with your 2nd substr... an index can be 2 digit... so you should use (strlen-1) :) Have also to note that `$q` must be an array in the construct (even if empty)

Comment: @Catharsis - many thanks for the suggestion.  The use of an array would definitely tidy up the 90 questions.  For the other (non-question) fields, I see you've kept the variable variable in place - i.e.  `$this->$key = htmlspecialchars($value);`  - My main question was relating to whether this was an inherently bad thing to do in general?  My research suggests you should never use them!

Comment: @freefalladdict If there aren't much other variables (less than 10 ?), you can explicit them... it would be more clear (here you have only 3).

Comment: @freefalladdict I would suggest that you can do it, although it does make your code slightly harder to follow, in the first instance comment it, if your worried make a function that JUST assigns your variables, write unit tests for it etc. Although PHP has the ability to dynamically assign variables to a class this should not be used, you should define them explicitly. An alternative is to make an object that does what you need with `$row` and return it, again I would suggest unit testing this.

Comment: @freefalladdict as a side note I don't quite understand why your pulling the variables out into the class anyway but then you know more about what your trying to do :) You can (not saying you should) just change the content in `$row` e.g `$row[$key] = htmlentities($row[$key)`. Just a suggestion :)